# Null not getting assigned to one of the fields Address.ZipCode

Tags: java

I have to classes

```
Student(having instance variables private int rollno,
    String studentName,
     int age, 
 Address address)
```

and

```
Address (having instance variables String streetName,
     String city,
 String zipCode )
```

all being private.

The below class populates the data from a StudentDetails.txt file as below(some fields can be missing. The missing fields are expected to replace by 0 for int and null for string).

```
1,Arjun,12,GhandiNagar,Pune,411020

5,Seema,,,,
```

`null` value is not getting assinged to `Adress.ZipCode` field.

```
    public class StudentDataManager implements DataManager 
    {
          public List<Student> populateData(String fileName)
          {
              List<Student> obj=new ArrayList<Student>();
              try 
              {
              File f=new File(fileName);
              Scanner in=new Scanner(f);
              while(in.hasNext())
              {
                  String s=in.nextLine();
                  String []array=s.split(",");

                  if(array[0].isEmpty())
                      array[0]="0";
                  int rollno=Integer.valueOf(array[0]);
                  if(array[1].isEmpty())
                      array[1]=null;
                  String studentName=array[1];
                  if(array[2].isEmpty())
                      array[2]="0";
                  int age=Integer.parseInt(array[2]);

                  Address temp1=new Address();
                  if(array[3].isEmpty())
                      array[3]=null;
                  if(array[4].isEmpty())
                      array[4]=null;
                  if(array[5].isEmpty())
                      array[5]=null;

                  temp1.setStreetName(array[3]);
                  temp1.setCity(array[4]);

                  temp1.setZipCode(array[5]);
                  Student temp2=new Student(rollno,studentName,age,temp1);
                  obj.add(temp2);
              }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              return obj;
   }
}
```

The code for class address is:

```
public class Address{
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String zipCode; 

    public Address(String streetName, String city, String zipCode) {
        this.streetName=streetName;
        this.city=city;
        this.zipCode=zipCode;
    }
    public Address() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }   
    public String toString()
    {
        return city+":"+streetName+":"+zipCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? How looks your Address class? What means "null value is not getting assinged to Adress.ZipCode field"

Comment: @MadProgrammer Example if Student.txt file contains something like this : 5,Seema,,,, or 1,Arjun,12,GhandiNagar,Pune,               where the last field reserved for ZipCode is empty than I am expected to populate data for that field as null.

Comment: @Jens I don't get any error but when I try to print them in main after overriding toString in Student and Address this is what I get  Notice the last field printed empty instead of null                      1:Arjun:12:Pune:GhandiNagar:411020
5:Seema:0:null:null:

Comment: Please add the code of class `Address` or try to debug your code, to see what is happend

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @Lathy please refer to my second comment (The problem being not getting a null value for-> 5:Seema:0:null:null:____ I should get null in place of ____. Like how I got ZipCode when it was present for->1:Arjun:12:Pune:GhandiNagar:411020

Comment: @Jens I have added the code for Address class

Comment: @Delfin: For your input ->5,Seema,,,,       Output: [5, Seema, , , , ] Please verify is this wat you need?

Comment: @Lathy For input ->5,Seema,,,, Output expected is: [5:Seema:0:null:null:null]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the empty string with `.split(regex)` version of `split` method.
Instead use `split(regex, limit)` and pass `-1` as limit.

```
String []array = s.split(",", -1);
```

**Edit :**

> I tried using that but still the last field is not printed null :( –  Delfin
>    For input ->5,Seema,,,, Output expected is: [5:Seema:0:null:null:null]

why will it print null for last field. What you are passing actually as text is `5,Seema,,,,` i.e. a space after last ,. If you want to get null for that too. than call trim() before isEmpty()

```
array[5].trim().isEmpty()
```

Comment: I tried using that but still the last field is not printed null :(

Comment: @Lathy thanks a ton that trim() solved my problem. (Y)

Comment: LOL what `@Lathy` means in your comment I advised to use `trim()`

Comment: @afzalex Thanks a million :P  :)